# api calls - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a api call but I can't success, everything goes fine until the call, and there stop everything and the function finish, what I do wrong?

```
Future<String> get() async {
var url = Uri.parse("https://10.0.2.2:7021/api/Auth/login");

var headers = {"content-type": "application/json"};
final msg = jsonEncode(
    {"username": "string", "password": "string", "email": "string"});

var response = await http!.post(url, body: msg, headers: headers);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print("Correct");
  return "Correct";
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);

  print("User not allowed");
  throw Exception("User not allowed");
}
```

}

[Mistake comes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFUpD.png)

[debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUtlP.png)

Comment: can you provide the error log ??

Comment: the error doesn't exist... see debug window

Comment: isn't `await` a blocking function?

Comment: yes, you are right, but how can I access to response then, if I remove await I'cant access .status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably imported the "wrong" `http`. Do it like that:

`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

You dont need to write `http!` because `http` is a package and is never null and since you are doing `http!` I guess you imported something wrong in your code.

EDIT:

Maybe your device can't reach `10.0.2.2` (or that port), you should set a timeout to find it out fast:

```
http.post(url, body: msg, headers: headers).timeout(
  const Duration(seconds: 3),
  onTimeout: () {
    // request timed out
    return http.Response('Error', 408);
  },
);
```

Comment: I fixed it know, but It's not resolving my problem... url of api "https://localhost:7021/swagger/index.html" but I have to access that on this way "https://10.0.2.2:7021/api/Auth/login" and it's not working

Comment: try timeout, I guess you devices can not reach that IP, try to open it on the chrome browser on that device just to see if you get a response there, if not, the error is not your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported http package like this?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

And use case like this

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: msg, headers: headers);
```

Comment: when I try to do that, It's error on "post", I can't compile it

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: looks like it doesnt recognize api, with 10.0.2.2 with port, I dont know why, url of api "https://localhost:7021/swagger/index.html"

Comment: I fixed that error I had instance of IOClient which name was http

Comment: Maybe your device is not reaching 10.0.2.2 (or it is but not through that port). see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

add .php to login in  the url :
https://10.0.2.2:7021/api/Auth/login.php
if you are working with php
or .py for python

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't use php or python, this is asp.net with flutter